# Flutter Hive throws TypeAdapter Error typeID: 0

Tags: flutter, hive, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am currently using Hive for a flutter app. Im getting an error of "The following HiveError was thrown building SaveBtn(dirty, state: _SaveBtnState#f8e25):
There is already a TypeAdapter for typeId 0."

I have tried reinstalling the app on the emulator multiple times and did flutter clean too.

**Main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  // if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(0)) {
  Hive.registerAdapter(ProductAdapter());
  // }

  boxProducts = await Hive.openBox<Product>('productsBox');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: CodeEntryPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Product.dart**

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'Product.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Product {
  @HiveField(0)
  final int productCode;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String productPrice;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String customerName;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String customerNumber;

  Product({
    required this.productCode,
    required this.productPrice,
    required this.customerName,
    required this.customerNumber,
  });
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'productCode': productCode,
      'productPrice': productPrice,
      'customerName': customerName,
      'customerNumber': customerNumber,
    };
  }

  // Implement toString to make it easier to see information about
  // each dog when using the print statement.
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Dog{productCode: $productCode, productPrice: $productPrice, customerName: $customerName},customerNumber: $customerNumber}';
  }
}
```

**Product.g.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'Product.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class ProductAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Product> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  Product read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Product(
      productCode: fields[0] as int,
      productPrice: fields[1] as String,
      customerName: fields[2] as String,
      customerNumber: fields[3] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Product obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.productCode)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.productPrice)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.customerName)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.customerNumber);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ProductAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
HiveError: There is already a TypeAdapter for typeld 0.
See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
```

Comment: Please replace the tag [hive] with [flutter-hive] in your question. [hive] is for _Apache Hive_.

Answer (score 1):

main.dart

```
...
Hive.registerAdapter(ProductAdapter());
if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(1)) {
    Hive.registerAdapter(ProductAdapter());
}
...
```

product.dart

```
...
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
...
```

Delete the `product.g.dart` file then After this run this command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

***Note:*** Make sure you have add `hive_generator` package in your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue again. "There is already a TypeAdapter for typeId 1." i even reinstalled the app

Comment: Have you run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` this command?

Comment: yupp, followed all the mentioned steps.

Comment: how many adapters are in your app?

Comment: just one adapter

Comment: Command successfully run or not?

Comment: yes, it created the .g.dart file

Comment: And what's the typeId in the .g.dart file?

Comment: `final int typeId = 1;`  same as the other file